# R List: How to get the length from a list stored in a key-value list?

Tags: r, list, data-structures, types

If I stored a list or vector in a key-value list, the list's length is 1 returned by length().

```
> i<-c(0,1,2,3,4)
> length(i)
[1] 5
> l <- list( r=2, i=i)
> l["i"]
$i
[1] 0 1 2 3 4

> length(l["i"])
[1] 1
```

Why? How to store a list or vector in a key-value list properly?

Comment: Try `length(l[["i"]])`. Using `length(l["i"])` returns a one-item list, hence the `length` being returned as "1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`length(l$i)` will do what you want...

```
> i<-c(0,1,2,3,4)
> i<-c(0,1,2,3,4)
> l <- list( r=2, i=i)
> l[i]
$r
[1] 2

$i
[1] 0 1 2 3 4

$<NA>
NULL

$<NA>
NULL

> l$i
[1] 0 1 2 3 4
> length(l$i)
[1] 5
```